# DIV scroll to bottom as content loads

Tags: php, jquery, scroll

I have a div called 'msg'

Within that DIV I'm running some php to read from a socket.
This part works fine and the results are shown in the 'msg' div.

But I'd like to have the dv scroll to the bottom, so I see new results as they are output.

The code I'm using is :

```
while (!feof($fp)) { 
    @ob_flush(); @flush();
    $response = stream_get_line($fp, 100, "\n"); 
    echo nl2br($response);
}
```

Can anyone advise how I get 'msg' to keep scrolling to the bottom as more output is added. ?

I've tried this but it didn't seem to help.

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height(); 
    $(window).scrollTop(scrollBottom);
}, 100);
```

Thanks

Comment: try to use the divs height and not the window-height.
And what is the timeout for? Just run that js after you loaded the list (I asume you use AJAX for that, just wait for the done-part).

Comment: Thanks - the list is constantly updating, hence the need to keep scrolling to the bottom..